# can I render some elements the way they look in material preview and how to do it?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine

So I have a a scene and I like some elements displayed in material tab so I want to render those this way. I d like to know how to do it for Cycles or Evee both

Edit: I need it for video

Comment: You mean, the Preview  of the Material Properties panel ? You can do a screenshot (either via your OS screenshot tool, or in Blender with Window/Save screenshot) then crop it with any image editor

Comment: no, haha. I need a video. Can t do so many screenshots!

Comment: In that case you can make a screencast (with a tool like VLC or ffmpeg or whatever depending of your OS). But I guess this is not what you want to do. Could you please be more specific, and show us exactly what you want to capture ? A screenshot would help

Comment: well I can t post screenshot because the customer doesn t want it, but I will try to be more specific. I am sure we all remember those days when Blender had an internal render, and it had a OpenGL Render option and it basically just rendered scene depending on the mode (solid, material, etc.). That`s what I want but in new Blender and with Cycles and Evee

Comment: Ok you should have start with that ! It's under View/Viewport Render Animation (in the viewport menu). It won't work with Cyles (as in  2.7x) but seems to work with Eevee as far as i know.

Comment: thanks! Evee should be enough=)

Answer (score 6):

First, you can do it in the 3D Viewport only. Find a View menu, and click the Viewport Render Animation. It will render the animation right from the viewport, using EEVEE if in solid or material preview mode. If you disable screen overlays, you can easily get nice renders in EEVEE this way, however, this is limited and inaccurate (not enough screen samples will be used, and softshadows can be blurry and flickering, among other limitations).

Here is the place where you can find View menu:
[image]

And then, find this menu command:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!//